# Was there an Islamically sanctioned reason for Aisha, the prophet's wife, to revolt against the election of Ali ibn Abu Talib for caliph by the Ummah?

Tags: history, war, ali, khilafah, aisha

Was her motive purely political, or was their an Islamically sanctioned reason?  The moderators said this question was a duplicate and referred to a link that had 4 detailed answers.  Most of the answers said Aisha's primary motivation was to bring the previous caliph's (Othman ibn Affan) murderers to justice.  While I certainly agree that this justice should be pursued, I fail to see how this would justify organizing a revolt (fitna) against Ali.

Ever since this revolt, the ummah have been in turmoil and never had a legitimate Islamic government.  The entire history from this point to the present day all we see are tyrants who either inherited rule in a dynasty chain or by violent conquest. Neither of which are sanctioned by Islam.

Again, was there an Islamically sanctioned reason for Aisha's fitna against Ali?

Comment: If the problem is "I fail to see how this would justify organizing a revolt (fitna) against Ali", why not ask about that instead?  E.g. the question could become "Why did Aisha persue justice for the murder of Othman ibn Affan by organizing a revolt (fitna) against Ali?"  Then it would be a different question.